# download html table into pdf in angularjs/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, pdf

i have a table in html format which looks like this

```
<table id="table" class="table table-bordered font" style="width: 100%; padding-top: 10px;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="bg-primary textalign">
                            <th>Details</th>
                            <th>SonVin Id</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Venue Name</th>
                            <th>City</th>
                            <th>Area</th>
                            <th>Amount</th>
                            <th>
                                <input type="checkbox" ng-click="allcheck()" ng-model="checkall" /><span style="margin-left: 10px;">Add Invoice</span>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="fdata in getdataintable">
                            <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="btndetails(fdata)" style="cursor: pointer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Details</a></td>
                            <td>{{fdata.sonvinid}}</td>
                            <td>{{fdata.date}}</td>
                            <td>{{fdata.venuename}}</td>
                            <td>{{fdata.location}}</td>
                            <td>{{fdata.area}}</td>
                            <td>{{fdata.amount}}</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="checkall" ng-model="fdata.checked" data-ng-click="calculateTotal(fdata)" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>

                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="totaldata in getdataintr">
                            <td colspan="6"></td>
                            <td>Total Amount</td>
                            <td>{{totaldata.amount}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

i am getting the data into this table through `angularJS`

and i want to give the option to the user to download this table into pdf format on a button click in `angulajs`

and this is the div which contains the button for download and go back

```
 <div style="margin-top:50px; margin-left:30vh;">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success active">Save And Download PDF</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger active">Don't Save And Select Again</a>
                </div>
```

i ain't created any functions for downloading data into `pdf`,

when the user clicks on `<a href="#" class="btn btn-success active">Save And Download PDF</a>` this button the table should be downloaded into `pdf`

What i need to do here?

Comment: You can use JSPDF https://parall.ax/products/jspdf

Comment: i dont know anything about this, What is this

Comment: would you like to look into the link which  have shared in my last comment.

Comment: i am unable to understand what is this

Comment: It allows you to programmatically generate with PDFs.